# What typeface is used by macOS to render unicode glyphs?

Tags: macos, font, design

What font is being used in the following screenshot (on a latest macOS/Safari) to render the Unicode glyphs?

[image]

The screenshot is taken from the page http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html

Is this font available somewhere publicly as an SVG?

(Cross-posted from [here.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/132256/what-typeface-is-used-by-macos-to-render-unicode-glyphs/))

Comment: Isn't it "Hiragino Sans" ?

Comment: In my environment (macOS Catalina/Safari/no additional fonts) the very same page looks different and e.g. 0x45 is properly displayed as handptleft (which is bit smaller than *White left pointing index* **in your screenshot** & without a cuff). The font (Wingdings Regular) is d/led (automatically) from alanwood.net. The *White left pointing index* looks like this though visiting the linked page: .

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I think you're right! Do you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this font is called "Hiragino Sans".

Answer (score 1):

All glyphs are Unicode glyphs!

In the absence of fonts specified in the webpage itself, Safari will use its default font, Time New Roman. However, TNR does not have glyphs in the range shown on this page  so Safari cascades to its default for each Unicode range.

For the glyphs in your screenshot, the pointing hand symbols, that seems to come from:

```
/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Symbols.ttf
```

Other glyphs on that page are from:

`/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Color Emoji.ttc`.

You can of course create outlined SVGs from any font character using a vector artwork editor like Adobe Illustrator, Affinity Designer, Graphic, or Inkscape.

Comment: Actually the glyphs in the Wingdings font are not Unicode, they are put at the code points reserved for Latin characters.  Hopefully this font has mostly disappeared from use now, since its glyphs were finally transferred to their own Unicode code points in Unicode 7 in 2014.

Comment: The pointing hands are now available in a wide range of fonts.  You can check which ones by going to those code points in the Character Viewer and looking at the font variation pane at the bottom right.   https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-emoji-and-symbols-on-mac-mchlp1560/10.14/mac/10.14

Comment: @TomGewecke You're right, of course, old 8-bit fonts aren't Unicode as such, though the OS doesn't 'turn on and off' Unicode when it uses them: my comment was aimed at correcting the inherent misunderstanding in the question. Even A to Z is "Unicode".